How to resolve "No module named 'imghdr'" error in Python 3.13 with Tweepy?
I'm currently using Python 3.13, and when I try to run a program that uses the Tweepy package, I get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imghdr'

After some research, it seems that the imghdr module might have been deprecated or removed in newer Python versions. However, my code relies on imghdr for image format verification, and this functionality seems to be critical for my program.
I've tried reinstalling Tweepy and checking my Python environment, but the error persists.
My questions:

Is imghdr indeed removed in Python 3.13?
What alternative libraries or approaches can I use to check image file types with minimal changes to my existing code?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this issue. Thank you!
I expected the program to run without issues, as it worked in previous Python versions. Since imghdr was previously part of the standard library, I assumed it would still be available in Python 3.13 or that Tweepy would handle any dependencies internally.

This might some day be fixed in Tweepy, but it might take a while. The issue has been recognized: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/2177, https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/2181, https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/2205.

This PEP removes a bunch of modules from the standard library, including imghdr, and proposes alternatives for some of them.
You can still install the package with
pip install standard-imghdr


I've stumbled at the same error trying to use tensorboard
